# Android Studio : Source code is not getting attached to the debug code

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

While debugging an application which is referencing the aar library whose source code I have , at the time of debugging at the point of calling a method in the aar library, I am prompted with the message as attached below : 
When I am attaching the source code folder to it by selecting the "Choose Sources" and try to debug ( F7 or F8) ,the code still remains in the .class file.
The debugger is in the auto mode ( in the setting) 
I have tried cleaning the library and the source folder and tried many times but I am not able to still jump into the source code.

[image]

Comment: kindly  write some comments before downvoting or please  feel free to edit the question if you think it needs to be !

Comment: Not sure about your description. Do you mean you have the xxxx.aar or you have the complete library project?

Answer (score 0):

don't use aar library. Since you hava source code, why don't you import the source code as a `Module`. Then dependency the `Module` into you main project.